# I got the first result only of the for loop in Django views

Tags: python, django

i have a PositiveIntegerField in a model, in which i need to loop through that model to check all the values of this field and get its results to use it in my views..

The Problem is when i did that i just get the value of the first row in the database only!

**models.py**

```
class RoomType(models.Model):
    hotel = models.ForeignKey(Hotel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    room_type = models.ForeignKey(RoomTypesNames, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    room_capacity = models.PositiveIntegerField() ## Thats the field i wanna check its value
```

**views.py**

```
def SearchHotels(request):
    x = None
    z = None
    t = None

    if request.method == 'GET':
        destination = request.GET.get('cityHotels')
        numAdultStr = request.GET.get('numAdult')
        numChild = request.GET.get('numChild')
        numAdult = int(numAdultStr)

        if destination:
            q_city2 = Q(hotel__city__name__icontains = destination)
            rooms2  = RoomType.objects.filter(q_city2)
      ################################
      ### next is my question:
            if rooms2:
                for r in rooms2:
                    if r.room_capacity < numAdult and numAdult % r.room_capacity == 0:
                        x = numAdult / r.room_capacity

### i want to loop through this query and check the values of 'room_capacity' in all models, but i only get the result of only the first row in my database
```

Comment: would you post the output of `rooms2.count()`?

Comment: standard rule: if you work with many elements then use `list` to keep all values. So maybe you should use list `x = []` to keep all results - `x.append()`.

Comment: c= rooms2.count()
 c= 8.0

Comment: use Break operation in look.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should get the last entry of your table unless your `order_by` is reversed. As @furas mentioned in comments, when you are dealing with multiple entry in a loop, its better to add the calculated values in a list.

But an alternative solution is to use [**`annotate`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/) with [**`conditional expression`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case) to use the DB to calculate the values for you:

```
from django.db.models import FloatField, IntegerField, ExpressionWrapper, F, Case, When, Value

room2 = RoomType.objects.filter(q_city2).annotate(
    x_modulo=ExpressionWrapper(
            numAdult % F('room_capacity'),
            output_field=IntegerField()
         )
    ).annotate(
        x=Case(
            When(
                room_capacity__lt=numAdult,
                x_modulo=0,
                then=numAdult/F('room_capacity')
            ),
            default_value=Value('0'),
            output_field=FloatField()
        )
    )
all_x = []
for r in room2:
    all_x.append(r.x)
print(all_x)
# or
print(room2.values('x'))

# filter usage
room2.filter(x__gt=0)
```

**Explanation:** In here, I am annotating of `x_modulo` which is modular value of numAdult and `room_capacity`. Then I am annotating the value of `x` which checks if room capacity is less than number of adults and value of `x_modulo` is 0. Then I am just annotating the fraction of numAdults and `room_capacity`.

Comment: thank you, but excuse me, i got this error in my template:
'ExpressionWrapper' object has no attribute 'annotate' **i passed it by re-ordering  brackets **
but, then i get another error :
unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'int' and 'Q' 
How i should fix that?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/d/store/ra3/raa_env/raa_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)

Comment: File "/mnt/d/store/ra3/raa_env/raa_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/mnt/d/store/ra3/raa_env/raa_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/mnt/d/store/ra3/hotels/views.py", line 34, in SearchHotels
    Q(room_capacity__lt=numAdult & Q(x_modulo=0),
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'int' and 'Q'

Comment: sorry and thanks for your patience but i got:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/d/store/ra3/raa_env/raa_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)

Comment: File "/mnt/d/store/ra3/raa_env/raa_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/mnt/d/store/ra3/raa_env/raa_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

Comment: File "/mnt/d/store/ra3/hotels/views.py", line 37, in SearchHotels
    output_field=FloatField()
  File "/mnt/d/store/ra3/raa_env/raa_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/expressions.py", line 829, in __init__
    raise TypeError("__init__() takes either a Q object or lookups as keyword arguments")
TypeError: __init__() takes either a Q object or lookups as keyword arguments

Comment: i knew and appreciate that you are doing your best .. but actually errors stopped, but it gave an unexpected empty queryset .. 
i m trying to figure out the reason ... and i ll follow with you ..
sorry for being late

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204617/discussion-between-desertcamel-and-ruddra).